# Are values of ConcurrentHashMap being synchronized by default?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

Below is a piece of code I found [here](https://plumbr.eu/blog/locked-threads/improving-lock-performance-in-java).
It mimics an online gameserver, where players can join to the tables.

```
public class GameServer {
  public Map<String, List<Player>> tables = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<Player>>();

  public void join(Player player, Table table) {
    if (player.getAccountBalance() > table.getLimit()) {
      List<Player> tablePlayers = tables.get(table.getId());

      synchronized (tablePlayers) {
        if (tablePlayers.size() < 9) {
          tablePlayers.add(player);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public void leave(Player player, Table table) {/*Method body skipped for brevity*/}

  public void createTable() {
    Table table = new Table();
    tables.put(table.getId(), table);
  }

  public void destroyTable(Table table) {
    tables.remove(table.getId());
  }
}
```

tablePlayers is one of the value of ConcurrentHashMap.

```
List<Player> tablePlayers = tables.get(table.getId());
```

Now that ConcurrentHashMap is already thread-safe, why do we still need to synchronize its value object when we want to use it?

```
  synchronized (tablePlayers) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Those are two totally different questions. Stick to one.

Comment: *Now that ConcurrentHashMap is already thread-safe, why do we still need to synchronize its value object when we want to use it?* You're not using **it**. You're using a value **retrieved** from it. ConcurrentHashMap doesn't protect its values, it just controls *access* to their references. Once you've obtained a reference, it's up to you to use it safely.

Answer (score 0):

Because using thread-safe objects in your program won't make your program thread-safe.

The code in question is here:

```
  synchronized (tablePlayers) {
    if (tablePlayers.size() < 9) {
      tablePlayers.add(player);
    }
  }
```

Obviously, it is intented to limit the size of the table to no more than nine players.

It won't work without `synchronized`.  There would be no way to know the size of the table when `tablePlayers.add(player)` is called.  The problem is, thread A could call `tablePlayers.size()`, and get back the number 8.  Then thread B could add a player to the table.  The thread A could test `8 < 9` (looks OK to me,) and add another player to the table.  The result would be ten players in the table.  Not what the author intended.

The fact that the table is "thread-safe" only means that the table's own internal data won't be corrupted when multiple threads access it.  It does *not* mean that the program will always do the right thing with the data.

Answer (score 0):

> Now that ConcurrentHashMap is already thread-safe, why do we still need to synchronize its value object when we want to use it?

CHM *is* thread-safe but that only means that it protects *itself* from concurrent operations.  Just because you are storing an object in a CHM doesn't then make the object magically thread-safe as well.  Once you retrieve the table-list from the CHM it is up to you to lock the object appropriately if it is going to be accessed by multiple threads.

In the case of your code, what happens if two threads call join at the same time?

```
synchronized (tablePlayers) {
   // race condition here because a test...
   if (tablePlayers.size() < 9) {
      // and then the add method
      tablePlayers.add(player);
   }
}
```

If there was not the `synchronized` block then the 2 threads might both check at the same time and see that the size of the table was 8 (for example) and then both go to add themselves to the table.  That's what a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) is all about.  Because there are 2 operations (a test and then an add), the `synchronized` is necessary to ensure that only 1 threads at a time can see if they can join a table *and* then join it.

Also, the `synchronized` block also protects the table-list itself which probably is not a `synchronized` collection itself.  Without the `synchronized` block there, then the 2 threads could write to the `List` at the same time and corrupt it.